# WebBackgrounder + Ninject

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

Does anyone have experience with using dependency injection with the [WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder) library?

In particular, I need to access my repository from within the job, and their lifetime dependent on the task lifetime. Preferably I would want to avoid property injection.

This is my WebBackgrounderSetup in App_Start:

```
public static class WebBackgrounderSetup
{
    static readonly JobManager _jobManager = CreateJobWorkersManager();

    public static void Start()
    {
        _jobManager.Start();
    }

    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        _jobManager.Dispose();
    }

    private static JobManager CreateJobWorkersManager()
    {
        var jobs = new IJob[]
    {
        new TmdbJob(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
    };

        var manager = new JobManager(jobs, new SingleServerJobCoordinator());
        manager.Fail(ex => Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(ex)));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with the WebBackgrounder, but the advice would be the same as for every multi-threaded application. The basic rules are:

- Don't pass services (dependencies) to other threads, since services are (or could be) dependent on a thread.
- Instead, resolve a new object graph at the beginning of that thread.
- For dependencies that have lifetime or caching that is specific to an HttpContext (such as the per request lifestyle), and need to be available on a background thread, you will need to configure it as an hibrid lifestyle (both per request and per thread).
- Do not register those dependencies on per thread, since ASP.NET is allowed to finish a request on a different thread than it started that request.

You can find more information here: [Work with dependency injection in multi-threaded applications](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to&referringTitle=Documentation#Multi_Threaded_Applications). That Wiki page is from a different DI framework, but most of it is applicable to Ninject.